# Sample Database for Full Text Searching

Tags: full-text-search, full-text-indexing, test-data, sample-data

I am looking to do some benchmarking on Full Text Search indexes in PostgreSQL, SQLServer and Lucene.

Any ideas on where to find a good big sample database to perform queries against?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: This question would also be on-topic at http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the great source would be wikipedia's database dump, since they contains really great amount of text. They are available here: http://dumps.wikimedia.org/

You could also try usenet archive, but there's harder to pick target language and the quality of language used is also lower.

Comment: Good point. It could also be STACKOVERFLOW's questions dump... :-)